# Why "cat" is not equal to "dog" in Python

Tags: python, string, operators

How does python compare strings via the inequality operators?

```
a = "cat"
b = "dog"

a < b
True
```

What properties of the strings results in `a < b == True`?

I've tried few other examples but still have no idea how Python compares them. Does Python compares strings like integers?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: because `c` comes before `d` in the alphabet?

Comment: look up lexicographic sort order

Answer (score 1):

Because python compares sequences (i.e. strings you have) *sequentially* by element values. "c" comes before "d" in Unicode, hence the result.

To compare length, use

```
len(a) == len(b)
```

The motivation behind this – having sequential comparison of elements, you can sort sequences in sane way. I.e. sorting list of names alphabetically is just `sorted(names_list)`. And this works exactly because strings will be compared alphabetically and sequentially.